# Terraform Azure create vnt-sub-db

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have some terraform code that creates a 3vm & vnet. but I cannot find work way to add 2 SGN and 3 subnets.
I have already read a lot of Terraform and Microsoft Documentation.
They have a lot of good solutions, but they not working on my terraform code.  I will be very glad full for some help.

The main.tf

```
resource "random_pet" "rg-name" {
  prefix    = var.resource_group_name_prefix
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name      = random_pet.rg-name.id
  location  = var.resource_group_location
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "Vnet" {
  name                = "Vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Subnet" {
  name                 = "subnet0"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.Vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Subnet2" {
  name                 = "subnet1"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.Vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}
#Associate subnet to subnet_network_security_group
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "public" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.Subnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.NSG.id
}


# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "Pub_IP" {
  name                = "PublicIP"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "NSG" {
  name                = "app_nsg_rule"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
#Create an Inbound rule for app nsg
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "app_nsg_rule" {
  name                          = "port8080"
  priority                     = 110
  direction                    = "inbound"
  access                       = "Allow"
  protocol                     = "Tcp"
  source_port_range            = "*"
  destination_port_range       = "8080"
  source_address_prefix        = "*"
  destination_address_prefix   = "*"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name  = azurerm_network_security_group.NSG.name
}
#Create an Inbound rule for db nsg
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "db_nsg_rule" {
  name                        = "port5432"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "5432"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.NSG.name
}
# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic1" {
  name                = "NIC1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "NicConf1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.Subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.Pub_IP.id
  }
#    ip_configuration {
#    name                          = "NicConf2"
#    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.Subnet2.id
#    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
#    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.Pub_IP.id
#  }
}

# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "NSG_Connect" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.nic1.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.NSG.id
}
# Create virtual machine
 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm_app" {
   count                 = 3
   name                  = "app_vm${count.index}"
   location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
   resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
   network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic1.id,count.index]
   vm_size               = "Standard_B2s"

   # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
   # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

   # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
   # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

   storage_image_reference {
     publisher = "Canonical"
     offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"
     sku       = "20_04-lts-gen2"
     version   = "latest"
   }
   storage_os_disk {
     name              = "disk${count.index}"
     caching           = "ReadWrite"
     create_option     = "FromImage"
     managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
   }
 }
# Import image from Image gallery
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Image_App" {
  name     = "Weight_Tracker_application"
  location = "EastUS"
}
#Create a Loadbalancer
resource "azurerm_lb" "LB" {
  name                = "loadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.Pub_IP.id
  }
}
#Create a Postgress Flexible Server
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "PS_SQL" {
  name                   = "sqlflexserver"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  version                = "12"
  administrator_login    = "postgres"
  administrator_password = "p@ssw0rd42"
  storage_mb             = 32768
  sku_name               = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
}
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database" "PS_FLEX" {
  name      = "db-server"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.PS_SQL.id
  collation = "en_US.utf8"
  charset   = "utf8"
}
```

Comment: what is SGN here ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a new clear code for this project, I just edit it...
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "NSG" {
  name                = "app_nsg_rule"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

Comment: what is the error you are getting even you haven't clear what is the SGN here and also in your code you are just creating lot of resource.Please stick to one problem.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT - no need to ask someone to post their answer - especially if it was an issue that is not really a reusable answer. Just vote to close as “typo or could not be reproduced”